# Raspberry Pi 2: Cannot SSH

Tags: ssh

I have a Raspberry Pi 2 that I was actively using for a few years and then stopped using for many years. Recently, I connected it to a Google Wifi router via wire. The web server I previously set up many years ago is working perfectly fine. However, I can neither ping nor ssh into it anymore. A port scan shows that port 80 is the only open port.

I wonder how I can debug from here. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: I wonder... do you think a *better* answer to your question might not be the one that fixed your problem? i.e. ***fix `iptables`***. You can answer your own question (that's actually encouraged here), **and** you can accept your answer - even if you've already accepted another one. You don't get points for selecting your own answer, but perhaps you make the site a bit more informative and accurate? Also, other answers can be upvoted (when you have enough rep to upvote). *Food for thought* - that's the purpose of this comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Nick Lansley's suggestion of attaching a keyboard and screen really helped me find the root cause. It turns out that my `iptables` settings assumed that the box was connecting to a specific subnet. It blocked all the ports since I switched subnet. Everything started working again after I purged the iptables rules.

Answer (score 1):

Hi Tom the likely cause is that the SSH server is using out of date cryptography libraries no longer used by your SSH client.

For now you will need to plug in a screen and keyboard and 'apt update' and 'apt upgrade' everything. Then reboot and see if that works. Worst case you may need to download and install the latest version of the operating system.

Best of luck!

Comment: I got it to work by attaching a screen and keyboard. It turns out that I had set iptables very restrictively and, since I have changed subnet, it filtered out all my ssh requests.

Answer (score 0):

Try to ping the Raspberry Pi from another device on your network to see if there is a response. If not, there may be an issue with the physical connection or IP configuration of the Raspberry pi.